# Java Map::hashCode() collision - why?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashcode, collision

The following code results in the same hash code being generated for the two maps, any ideas?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Foo
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Map map;

        map = new HashMap();

        map.put("campaignId", 4770L);
        map.put("location", "MINI_PROFILE");
        map.put("active", "true");
        map.put("lazy", true);

        System.out.println(map.hashCode());

        map = new HashMap();

        map.put("campaignId", 4936L);
        map.put("location", "MINI_PROFILE");
        map.put("active", "true");
        map.put("lazy", false);

        System.out.println(map.hashCode());


    }
}
```

The result is:

```
-1376467648
-1376467648
```

Simply changing the key names is enough to make the code generate two different hash codes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply coincidence, I suspect... there are *bound* to be collisions, and in this case it looks like the relevant different bits in the first value are being lost, effectively.

However, it shouldn't make any difference - anything using hash codes *must* cope with collisions.

EDIT: It's just the way the hashes happen to be calculated. This code shows what's going on:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        AbstractMap.SimpleEntry[] entries = {
            new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry("campaignId", 4770L),
            new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry("campaignId", 4936L),
            new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry("lazy", true),
            new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry("lazy", false)
        };
        for (AbstractMap.SimpleEntry entry : entries) {
            System.out.println(entry + ": " + entry.hashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
campaignId=4770: -1318251287
campaignId=4936: -1318251261
lazy=true: 3315643
lazy=false: 3315617
```

So in one pair the first map has a hash 26 *less* than the second map, and in another pair the first map has a hash 26 *more* than the second map.

`AbstractMap` just sums hash values (one way of making sure that ordering is irrelevant) so the two end up with the same hash code.

It's really down to `Boolean.hashCode()` which looks like this:

```
return value ? 1231 : 1237;
```

... and `Long.hashCode()` which looks like this:

```
return (int)(value ^ (value >>> 32));
```

Given the values they happened to pick in `Boolean.hashCode()`, if your `long` values are only 26 apart (or 26 * 2^32 apart) then you'll run into the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is just a coincidence. From the Javadoc for AbstractMap#hashCode():

> The hash code of a map is defined to be the sum of the hash codes of each entry in the map's entrySet() view.

And for Entry#hashCode():

> Returns the hash code value for this map entry. The hash code of a map entry e is defined to be:

```
 (e.getKey()==null   ? 0 : e.getKey().hashCode()) ^
 (e.getValue()==null ? 0 : e.getValue().hashCode())
```

So hash codes for maps are based on both the keys AND the values contained in the map. You're just experiencing a odd situation where two maps have the same hash code, with no apparent reason.

Answer (score 3):

Collisions happen. In fact, you could override hashCode() to always return 0 for every `HashMap` and it would be correct (altough it would make a lot of structures **slow**).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a coincident.

String objects are same in both. Same object will give same hashcode.